# SQL Server CPU vs. Storage Bottlenecking

Tags: sql-server, performance

I've read quite a bit about SQL Servers using SSDs performing much better than traditional hard drives.  In load tests with my app in a test environment, though, I'm able to keep my test DB server (SQL 2005) pegged between 75% and 100% CPU usage without much of a strain on disk access (as far as I can tell).  My data set is still pretty small; database backups are under 100 MB.  The test server I'm using is not new, but is also no slouch.

So, my questions:

1. Is the CPU the bottleneck (as opposed to the storage) because the dataset is small and therefore fits in memory?
2. Will this change once the dataset grows so paging is necessary?
3. Approximately how big (as a percentage of system memory) does the dataset have to get before SQL Server starts paging?  Or does that depend on a lot of other factors?
4. As the app and its dataset grows, are there other bottlenecks that will tend to crop up besides CPU, storage, and lack of proper indexes?

Comment: SSDs are *so much faster* at random access. It is ridiculous. It's like ... a floppy disk vs. a "normal" HDD. Well, perhaps not quite. They are also *much* more expensive per GB and perhaps less long-lived due to increased throughput... and do remember that, given enough memory, SQL Server is not a slug, even with "normal" HDDs...

Comment: I know, I've seen side-by-side comparisons of MBPs booting and launching all of Adobe CS5 from an SSD and an HDD.  Crazy.

Comment: The reason why I use SSDs at home and advocate SSDs at work... the performance is pretty good, and the lifetime issue can be resolved quite easily with good practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. Yes
3. If you have SQL Server configured to use as much memory as it can get, probably when it exceeds the max system memory. But it's very setup dependant on what causes paging (the query that is being executed is the most prevalent cause).
4. I/O between the request machine and server is the only one that I can think of, and that only matters if you are retrieving large datasets. I also would not group a lack of indexes as a bottleneck, rather indexes enable better performance with regard to searching.

Comment: The queries being run by this app do a LOT of joins; is that what you mean by searching?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the CPU is the bottleneck on your dedicated SQL-Server machine, you don't have to worry about disk speed (assuming nothing's wrong with the machine). SQL-Server WILL use heavy memory caching. SQL-Server has built-in strategies to perform best under a given load and available resources. Just don't worry about it!